# MongoDB, Java and Freemarker Templates (FLT)

Tags: java, mongodb, freemarker

I'm working on this web project with: Java, MongoDB and Freemarker Templates (FTL)

The data is sent to the FTL pages within a Map.

Now I would like to know if it's possible to convert the result from a Mongo query straight into a Map and then send this to the FTL template.

For example:
I would like to query all the members from a collection and put this in Map to use in the FTL template.

```
        public Map<String, Object> getAllMembers() {
            DBCollection collection =database.getCollection("members");
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
            DBCursor cur = collection.find(query);
            DBObject one = cur.next();

            HashMap<String,Object> result = one;

            return result;
        }
```

Or is this not possible and I would need to loop over the results putting each value into a Map? Like this:

```
        public Map<String, Object> getAllMembers(f){
            DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("members");
            DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
            Map<String,Object> itemMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            DBObject one;
            while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                one = cursor.next();
                itemMap.put((String)one.get("id"),one.get("name"));
            }
            return itemMap;
        }
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Comment: I find the examples confusing, because they don't look like if they try to achieve the same things. In the first example, you only return the first `DBObject`, and try to convert it to a `Map` apparently (`one.toMap()` does that I believe). In the second one you iterate through all the `DBObject`-s, an build an id-to-name `Map` from them (dropping all the other fields). So how exactly do you want to access the members in the templates, ideally?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you need:

```
public Map<String, Object> fetch(DB db, String collName, String key, String value){

    Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(collName);
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put(key, value);
    DBCursor cur = coll.find(query);
    while(cur.hasNext()) {
        result.putAll(cur.next().toMap());
    }
    return result;
}
```